# How to implement "symmetric non-strict or" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function that have the following properties

```
symmetricLazyOr :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
symmetricLazyOr True _|_ === True
symmetricLazyOr _|_ True === True
```

And otherwise it works like the normal `or`.

Is it even possible in Haskell?

**UPDATE**

This question is focus on semantic rather than implementation detail. Intuitively, `or` shall be symmetric, which means `or a b === or b a` for all given `a` and `b`. However, this is not true in Haskell since `or _|_ True === _|_` whilst `or True _|_ === True`.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking here (what is your "_ | _" - Bottom?) - If you are talking about Bottom than the problem is: you have to start somewhere (usually from the top of the cases) and there you run into trouble - I don't think that this is possible on first glance but I will think a bit about it

Comment: Hmm ... you could possible hack something but trying both arguments in forks or something but that just feels ugly to me

Comment: BTW: a better title for the question might be "symmetric "non-strict" or)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. What is your use case?

Comment: @JanDvorak Simple: parallel computing, carpet search, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In other words, you're looking for a function that, given two arguments, attempts to evaluate them both and is true if either argument is true?  And in particular, a `True` result will be returned so long as at least one argument is `True` and not bottom?

Assuming that's correct, this is possible, but not purely.  In order to implement it, you need to race two threads to evaluate each of the branches.  The [unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html) package has some functions for dealing with cases like this (including the parallel-or function `por`).  Another option is [lvish](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lvish), which should also work in this case as I understand it.

Comment: unamb is something of an implementation detail, [lub](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lub) is where the money's at.  There's lots of interesting things you can do with lub, for example [non-strict memoization](http://conal.net/blog/posts/nonstrict-memoization).

Comment: @luqui: that's true, except the `unamb` package provides exactly the function the OP asks about.  And if you like `lub` you should really check out `lvish`, which is even more powerful.

Comment: `lvish` is cool, thanks.  It's hard for me to call it "more powerful" -- it's a different model and embeds in a different way.  AFAICT one cannot implement the other.

Comment: @luqui: I believe all that's necessary to implement `lub` with `lvish` is to reify the upper-bound information into the appropriate lattice.  If you have a `lub` combining function that isn't based on a lattice, I suspect that you'll have problems (non-determinism) with `lub` too.

Comment: the difference is that `lub`'s lattice is not decidable, so this reification is impossible.

Comment: @luqui: can you provide an example of a useful case where `lub`'s lattice is not decidable and deterministic?  The only ones that come to mind for me are IMHO rightfully disallowed by the `lvish` approach.

Comment: the domain of functions `Nat -> Bool`.  (I'm not going to engage "useful" -- mathematical facts are good enough for me.)